# Placing two <li> in one line html

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a form, where I have a side navbar. I have around 15-20 elements to  be displayed. I want two `<li>` in one line. Each `<li>` contains a link to a modal. When an `<li>` is clicked, a modal opens.

This is how I've written:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
         <h4 class="sidebar-brand">Select Field Type</h4>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SingleLine_Modal">Single Line</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PickList_Modal">Pick List</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiSelect_Modal">Multi Select</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiLine_Modal">Multi Line</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Email_Modal">Email</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Phone_Modal">Phone Number</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Mobile_Modal">Mobile Number</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Date_Modal">Date</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Time_Modal">Time</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DateTime_Modal">Date-Time</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CheckBox_Modal">Checkbox</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Radio_Modal">Radio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Decimal_Modal">Decimal</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Number_Modal">Number</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AutoNumber_Modal">Auto Number</a></li>

   </div>
```

This is how it looks now:

```
Single Line
Pick List
Multi Select
Multi Line
Email
Phone Number
Mobile Number
Date
Time
Date-Time
Checkbox
Radio
Decimal
Number
Auto Number
```

But, I want it to look like this:

```
|   Single Line   |  Pick List    |
| Multiple Select |    Email      |
| Phone Number    | Mobile Number |
|     Date        |    Time       |
|   Checkbox      |   Radio       |
|   Decimal       |   Number      |
|  Auto Number    | (further li)  |
```

This is my css:

```
  #sidebar-wrapper {
        z-index: 1000;
        position: fixed;
        display: table-cell;
        left: 250px;
        width: 0;
        height: 600px;
        margin-left: -250px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: #000;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    .sidebar-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 250px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .sidebar-nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        text-indent: 20px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }
.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}



     .sidebar-nav li a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #999999;
        }

        .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
        }

        .sidebar-nav li a:active,
        .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
            height: 65px;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 60px;
        }

        .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
            color: #999999;
        }

        .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
            color: #fff;
            background: none;
        }
```

What else should I do, so that I can get it in the way I want?

I want it that way because, once the number of `<li>` contents increase, it goes down, and becomes invisible. The last option becomes invisible or partially visible. I order to achieve it in the way I want, what should I add or remove?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `column-count` property of CSS3.

Just like:

```
.sidebar-nav {
  column-count: 2; /* Specify no. of columns */
}
```

Look at the snippet below:

```css
.sidebar-nav {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <h4 class="sidebar-brand">Select Field Type</h4>
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SingleLine_Modal">Single Line</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PickList_Modal">Pick List</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiSelect_Modal">Multi Select</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiLine_Modal">Multi Line</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Email_Modal">Email</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Phone_Modal">Phone Number</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Mobile_Modal">Mobile Number</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Date_Modal">Date</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Time_Modal">Time</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DateTime_Modal">Date-Time</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CheckBox_Modal">Checkbox</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Radio_Modal">Radio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Decimal_Modal">Decimal</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Number_Modal">Number</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AutoNumber_Modal">Auto Number</a></li>

   </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want only two in one line, bro.

Comment: Nice!!!! Now that's some fresh knowledge bites for me. Yummy!!!!  :Q

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this :

```css
ul, li{
list-style:none;
}

.f-l{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <h4 class="sidebar-brand">Select Field Type</h4>
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
         <li>
           <ul class="f-l">
             <li>Single Line<li>
             <li>Multiple Select<li>
             <li>Phone Number<li>
             <li>Date<li>
             <li>Checkbox<li>
             <li>Decimal<li>
             <li>Auto Number<li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul class="f-l">
             <li>Pick List<li>
             <li>Email<li>
             <li>Mobile Number<li>
             <li>Time<li>
             <li>Radio<li>
             <li>Number<li>
           </ul>
        </li>
      
  
      </ul>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS selectors `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` to give `float: left` and `float: right`. You may need to add some other settings, not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
ul {
  width: 250px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This JSFiddle should help you:

https://jsfiddle.net/9tyrhwec/

```
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <h4 class="sidebar-brand">Select Field Type</h4>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td><li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SingleLine_Modal">Single Line</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PickList_Modal">Pick List</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiSelect_Modal">Multi Select</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiLine_Modal">Multi Line</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Email_Modal">Email</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Phone_Modal">Phone Number</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Mobile_Modal">Mobile Number</a></li></td>
    <td><li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Date_Modal">Date</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Time_Modal">Time</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DateTime_Modal">Date-Time</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CheckBox_Modal">Checkbox</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Radio_Modal">Radio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Decimal_Modal">Decimal</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Number_Modal">Number</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AutoNumber_Modal">Auto Number</a></li></td>
  </tr>
  </table>


  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be like this - break it up into 2 ul's that are floated next to each other:

```
<style>
    .sidebar-nav_wrapper
    {
       float: left;
       margin-left: 5px;
       width: 250px;
       position: relative;
       height: 650px;
    }
</style>

<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <h4 class="sidebar-brand">Select Field Type</h4>
        <div class="sidebar-nav_wrapper">

          <ul class="sidebar-nav">

             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SingleLine_Modal">Single Line</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PickList_Modal">Pick List</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiSelect_Modal">Multi Select</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiLine_Modal">Multi Line</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Email_Modal">Email</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Phone_Modal">Phone Number</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Mobile_Modal">Mobile Number</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-nav_wrapper">
          <ul class="sidebar-nav">
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Date_Modal">Date</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Time_Modal">Time</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DateTime_Modal">Date-Time</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CheckBox_Modal">Checkbox</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Radio_Modal">Radio</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Decimal_Modal">Decimal</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Number_Modal">Number</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AutoNumber_Modal">Auto Number</a></li>
 </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This works, but there is a hover problem. When I select something from the right side, only that element is highlighted. But, when I select something from the right side, the full line is highlighted. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: Please try it now. I had made some edits that weren't saved for some reason, but they are in there now.

Comment: This scrambled everything. All the li got mingled into one.

Comment: I made sume changes to the sidebar-nav_wrapper definition. Please update and try it. You may need to play with the width & height a little.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. One column is displayed and below that the other column is displayed. Can you please refer to my css provided above and tell me the corrections?